# How are JavaScript expression evaluated?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, can someone explain the results of the 2 following expressions:

"4" + 4 and  4 + "4"

Thanks!

Comment: it prints "44" both are assumed to be strings

Comment: You should get a JavaScript reference to work out these sorts of basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    1+'1'+1 = '111'
    1+1+'1' = '21'
   '1'+(1+1) = '12'
   '1'+1+1 = '111'
```

Javascript performs math until it hits a string and then switches to concatenation, and it also follows regular formula rules run () operations first.

Comment: Not necessarily the best answer but I understood what I wanted: expressions are evaluated from left to right and I understood the concatenation of the + operator. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Both will result in the `String`:

```
"44"
```

This is because the `+` operator serves 2 purposes -- addition and concatenation. And, if either operand is a `String` (or is cast to a `String` by the internal [`ToPrimitive()`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1)) they'll be concatenated.

This is described [in the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) as:

> 7) If [Type](http://es5.github.io/#Type)(*lprim*) is String or [Type](http://es5.github.io/#Type)(*rprim*) is String, then
>
> a) Return the String that is the result of concatenating [ToString](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8)(*lprim*) followed by [ToString](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8)(*rprim*)
>
> 8) Return the result of applying the addition operation to [ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3)(*lprim*) and [ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3)(*rprim*). See the Note below [11.6.3](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.3).

If you want to ensure addition, you can use [`parseFloat()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.3) or the [unary `+`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6) on each:

```
var a = "4", b = 4;

console.log(parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)); // 8;

console.log((+a) + (+b)); // 8, extra parenthesis for clarity
```

Answer (score 1):

they'll both be '44'.  The presence of the '4' as a string casts the whole operation to a string, so the two characters are concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

Cited from: http://javascript.about.com/od/variablesandoperators/a/vop10.htm

> One thing that can be confusing to beginners is that JavaScript uses +
>   with text strings to mean something completely different from what it
>   means with numbers. While with numbers + means add the numbers
>   together with text + means concatenate them together. Concatenation
>   basically means joining one text string onto the end of the first so
>   that "my"+"book" gives "mybook" as a result. Where beginners tend to
>   get confused is that while 3+3 gives 6, "3"+"3" gives "33".
>
> You can also use += with text strings to directly add the variable or
>   text on the right onto the end of the text string variable on the
>   left.
>
> Mixing Data Types
>
> Additional confusion can arise when you are working with variables
>   that are of different types. All operations require that the variables
>   that they are operating on both be of the same type. Before JavaScript
>   is able to perform any operations that involve two different data
>   types, it must first convert one of the variables from one type to the
>   other. You can't add a number to a text string without first either
>   converting the number to text or the text to a number.
>
> When converting between data types we have two choices. We can allow
>   JavaScript to do the conversion for us automatically or we can tell
>   JavaScript which variable that we want to convert.
>
> JavaScript will attempt to convert any text string into the number
>   equivalent when performing subtraction, multiplication, division, and
>   taking remainders. Your text string will actually need to contain
>   something that JavaScript can convert to a number (i.e., a string like
>   "10") in order for the conversion to work.
>
> If we use + then this could either mean that we want to convert the
>   string to a number and add then or that we want to convert the number
>   to a string and concatenate them. JavaScript can only perform one of
>   these two alternatives. It always converts numbers to strings (since
>   that will work whether the string contains a number or not).
>
> Here are some examples.
>
> 1. "5" - 3 = 2;
> 2. "5" + 3 = "53"
> 3. 2 + "7" = "27"
> 4. 5 + 9 + "1" = "141"
>
> Since subtraction only works with numbers 1 converts the text string
>   into a number before doing the subtraction.
>
> In 2 and 3 the number is converted to a text string before being
>   concatenated (joined) to the other text string.
>
> In 4 the leftmost addition is done first. Since these are both numbers
>   they are actually added together and not treated as text. The result
>   of this first addition leaves us with a similar situation to the third
>   example and so the result of that addition is converted to text and
>   concatenated.
>
> To actually force JavaScript to convert a text string to a number we
>   can use Number("3") or alternatively to force JavaScript to convert a
>   number to a text string we can use String(5).

Comment: If this is a quotation, the source should be attributed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions in JS work on two prime principles.

1. B O D M  A(includes concat) S
2. Left to right order of execution

However, its not straight forward

## for + operator

as far as it encounters numbers it will do math addition using left to right execution, However,as soon as it encounters a string, it concatenates the result (that's calculated till encountering a string) with rest of the expression.

```js
//left to right execution
console.log(10+10+"10") //2010, (10+10) of numtype + "10" of stringtype concat(20+"10") 
                                 
console.log(10+10+"10"+10+10) //20101010,  
//(10+10) of number  type + "10" stringtype(now since a string is enc.) + (10+10) of number type would act as strings and get concatenated = 20+"10"+"1010"

console.log("10"+[10,10,10]+10) //1010,10,1010
//"10"of stringtype + array of numtypes + 10 of numtype
// "10" concats with first element of array, last number 10 concats with last element of array.
```

## for all other operators such as -,*,/,^...

if all occurrences are numbers/numbers as string, it will do the respective math operation treating "numbers as string" to be numbers.

```js
console.log("10"-10) //0
console.log("10"/10) //1
console.log("10"*10) //100
console.log(10+"10"*10) //110 //BODMAS 
console.log(Math.pow(10,"10")) //10000000000
```

if there are occurrences of non-numeric strings,arrays,objects in the middle of expression that involve (-,*,/,^...)math operations, it will always return NaN

```js
console.log(10-{id:1,name:"hey"}-10) //NaN
console.log(10-10-"hey"-10-10-10) //NaN
console.log("hey"/10) //NaN
console.log("hey"* 3) //NaN
console.log(["hey","hey"]*"3") //NaN
console.log("10"/[10,10,10]/10) //NaN
```